# hide toolbar buttons in Chrome / Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, toolbar, chromium

Am a large keyboard user, and I've never hit back/forward/refresh or the favourite buttons on my browsers. Within safari, I can modify each of the buttons that appear.

I wish in Chrome to only be able to see the address bar, and the page. Is this possible?

Comment: not possible, but you may express your wishes here: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/request.py?contact_type=feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I looked as much as I could but I couldn't find a way to do this. You can suggest this feature though http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome?hl=en

Comment: just submitted a the suggestion.

Also added that they should have the ability to hide the address bar, and have it transient in when I hit "ctrl/command+L" - like now with activating it.

a browser is a window to the internet, I don't want to be distracted with borders/buttons/address-bars

:)

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the default buttons (left/right/refresh). There is a feature request on this where you can vote for it at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24498.

You can hide/move extension toolbar buttons. You can hide them by right-clicking and choosing hide. You can move them around by dragging them.

Comment: This only works on Windows, probably?

Comment: No, works on OSX. I am doing it right now :).

Comment: I can't right-click on any of the Back/Forward or the Refresh buttons. I *can* hide the extension buttons, but not the ones the OP wants to have hidden. Can you add a screenshot, maybe?

Comment: I'm sorry, I answered subject but not detailed question. You unfortunately can't change the built-in buttons. There is a feature request on that, I will add it to my answer.